# Top margin doesn't recover the background color

Tags: html, css

I'm a CSS beginner trying to customise my WordPress blog by using a custom.css file.

I'd like to add a margin to the top of a div in order to create a separation with the header.

I tried to just change the style like this :

[image]

But when I do so the top margin background is black. It doesn't recover the grey background of the div which contains this div.

Is there any trick to do that easily ? Can I use a border instead of a margin for instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the div which is causing the issue

```
.html_stretched #wrap_all {
    background-color: #333333;
}
```

Set `maring-top` as you are trying and add following in your custom.css file

```
.html_stretched #wrap_all {
    background-color: #e5e4e4 !important; 
}
```

It will overwrite the default css and set the background grey and you will have your content body separated from header.

Answer (score 1):

[image: box css]

According to that image, maybe you want to specify the padding-top instead of margin-top.

Comment: OP wants to separate the content body from header, padding will not separate header from content body but just push the content further down.